# ARP incomplete on the router connected to the gateway

Tags: networking, arp

Here in my office we have a network consisting of the gateway (router) from the ISP, and less than 15 clients (computers). I noticed the network slowed down a lot,
even when there was only 1 client connected, then I found out that the ARP table is filled with incomplete requests. All the incomplete requests are IP addresses which do not exist in the internal LAN. Because of this even pings from a computer (internal) to an outside network will start dropping. Can anyone help me understand what might be the issue? Exclude the case of loop because I tried to use it with one PC also.

Comment: You sure there's only one device? It sounds like something is spamming the network with bad requests for an IP maybe...

Comment: Incomplete ARP entries will have the IP address but missing the MAC address. Which IP addresses do you see on these entries and how do they relate to the network?

Comment: The ip address are address which are on the same subnet but not occupied by the computers

Comment: Do you have any switches on the network? (Please add in comments the name of the person addressed, like `@harrymc:`)

Comment: It sounds like something is scanning your network. It could be a user or malware.

Comment: @harrymc: No there is no switch, its a d-link hub.

Comment: @Ron Maupin ..thats one thing i suspect, i want to know if there a way to proof that .

Comment: If it's a hub, then run Wireshark on a PC to inspect the source MAC address to find out which device is doing it.

Comment: You may try to reboot or reset the router to restart from zero. If the d-link is in addition to the ISP modem, reboot them both.

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the incoming traffic using Wireshark, we found that there was TCP syn packet coming from many user computers towards the gateway router using port 445, unfortunately we were using ADSL as a gateway and the ADSL couldn't stand all the load and it will start dropping packet. As a temporary solution we block the port 445 and the traffic seems fine.

Comment: Towards the router itself, or through the router towards Internet hosts? The former probably means the router has "SMB file sharing" running; the latter usually means malware infection across the whole LAN.

Comment: Its the second case and Yes, the whole LAN is infected with malware.